# PHP не передается значение из поля ввода в php код

Tags: php

Не работает РНР код, когда ввожу имя, и нажимаю "ОК" то значение из поля ввода не передается в РНР код.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        php code
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <form method="get" action="index.php">
                <input name="name" type="text">
                <input type="submit" value="OK">
            </form>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        php code
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php
                echo $_POST["name"];
            ?>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `method="get"` замените на `method="post"`

Comment: Заменил, все то же самое

Comment: а что происходит?

Comment: заменил - сохрани

Comment: Вы значение передаете в POST, затем обновляете страницу (submit'итe) и ждете, что оно будет отображаться в заголовке..?

Comment: Да, например я пишу в поле имя, нажимаю submit, и страница должна отобразить имя которое я ввел.

Comment: @АлександрКузнецов. Лично я вижу, что у вас все события разворачиваются в одном и том же файле index.php - Только в верхнем примере кода у вас только форма, а в нижнем только заголовк. Скажите,  между нажатием submit и ожидание вывода $_post - вы еще перезагружаете страницу? 

потому что как post так и get хранит данные до перезагрузки. Если хотите более длительного храниения используйте Куки, Сессию, БД или ЛокалСторадж

Comment: больше похоже что это два разных файла

Comment: По учебнику писал этот код, там про это ничего не сказано. Написано было только то- что при нажатии OK, на страницу выведется php код с информацией что я передал в окно ввода. Например пишу Володя, нажимаю ОК, и меня перебрасывает на страницу с php кодом с текстом Володя...

Comment: А веб-сервер то есть вообще в наличии?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в верстке форма лежит в заголовке. Не надо так. Используйте вот такую конструкцию для достижения ожтдаемого результатата

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        php code
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1><?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?></h1>
         <form method="POST" action="index.php">
             <input name="name" type="text">
             <input type="submit" value="OK">
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А как можно подключить php код прям в сам html? или в любой документ с форматом .html?

Comment: просто переименуйте файл index.html в index.php. PHP код принципиально обрабатывается лишь в файлах с расширнием PHP. Это считайте пунктиком серверов, они как французы, не признают других языков

Comment: @4kilograms "код принципиально обрабатывается лишь в файлах с расширнием PHP" --- неправда. Не надо писать то, что не знаете... Код обрабатывается в файле с любым расширением, хоть даже `.wtf`. Как сервер настроен, так и будет обрабатываться